# How can I Map Dynamic Urls in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

So my plan is

`/somewhere/{Dir}/{SubDIr}/{File}`

`somewhere` is a route to handle this part of directories and Sub Directories, my problem is that I couldn't find a way to route that, I tried rewriting a Url, but that's not what i need. Also I don't know how many subdirs I will have, which makes the process even more difficult.

On the other hand a great example of what I have been looking to achieve is GitHub. you see, the first part of their url is static, which is
`https://github.com/{User}/{Repo}`

and then the dynamic part comes:

- `https://github.com/{User}/{Repo}/tree/{branch}` to see the base of repo.
- `https://github.com/{User}/{Repo}/blob/{branch}/{dirs}/{file}` to see specific files.

I am looking to do exactly that

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

So, After Searching a lot, I found what they call a Match-all parameter, which can be used like:

Program.cs **!!Needs to be in all Applications running in .net core 3.1 or lower, i test without it on .net 5.0 and it work**

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.UseCorrectCatchAllBehavior", true);
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Blazor

```
@page "/"
@page "/index/{*Path}"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h1>Path is @Path</h1>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
         await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Path is: {Path}");
    }
}
```

On apis, it would be:

Controller:

```
  public class TestRouteController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/source/{*path}")]
        public string Invoke(string path)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(path);
            return path;
        }
    }
```

## Result:

### Blazor:

url:

[image: BlazorResult]

result in browser console:

[image: BlazorResult]

### WebApi:

url:

[image: ControllerResult]

terminal:

[image]

browser response:

[image]